# User and PasswordReset - different aggregates?

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

Kind of basic thing in DDD.

Here is a basic case for many user-based systems. There is a User object/entity. User can create password reset (or email verification), which will trigger email sent, and then after correct user actions password data will be reset (or user email will be verified in case of verification).

What should be considered when deciding if User aggregate will include Password Resets and Verifications, or those should be different aggregates?

Usually, when not thinking in terms of aggregates, I was creating different collcations (io noSQL db) of Users, Resets, Verifications.

Not I'm building EventSourcing based system, and thinking how it is better to design in terms of aggregates.

I think this kind of case should be quite typical for many projects, I will appreciate any input from experienced people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These use-cases are subject to the DDD, Event sourcing is *kinda* irrelevant here. Whether to create a new Aggregate type or not depends on the invariants and the consistency requirements (strong vs eventual consistency).

In this particular use-case of password resetting, the question is whether you allow a blocked user to request a password reset or not. If there is another Aggregate responsible for this, i.e. `UserPassword`, then there is a *small* possibility that a blocked user could request a password reset because of eventual consistency between the two Aggregate types. You could say that it does not matter (it does not have any negative impact in the business) because even if the user requests a password reset he could not authenticate anymore because the user is blocked. So it strongly depends on the Domain.

In general, you should favor smaller Aggregates but without breaking the invariants. You can read [this](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838) essay by Vaughn Vernon about designing Aggregates.

> Not I'm building EventSourcing based system, and thinking how it is better to design in terms of aggregates.

You should use the entire DDD approach, not just the Aggregate tactical pattern but also the strategic patterns like bounded contexts and context maps.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input much